# How to add a remote file to .htaccess file for webcaching?

Tags: apache, cache

I have the following code in my *.htaccess* file that caches several file extension types:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I would like to add a remote file to the list `www.example.com/js/jqueryvalid.js`... Is this possible?

Comment: You shouldn't care too much about 'remote' cache times, I assume your trying to score high on a speed test. Often CDN's will use much lower cache times but even with a low time they generally are faster than internal hosting with high cache times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control files on another domain with *.htaccess* or any other means without making changes on the other server. So, no, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a local js file which loads the remote js file script.

```
$.getScript("url")
```

Now add this local file to .htacces and set expiry.
Not sure if it works. Check.